# Perl installation using docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to build the docker image with perl installation. but facing issues with the make command. it says No makefile found.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux
WORKDIR /shared
RUN yum -y install gcc
ADD http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.22.1.tar.gz /shared
RUN tar -xzf perl-5.22.1.tar.gz
RUN /shared/perl-5.22.1/Configure -des -Dprefix=/opt/perl-5.22.1/localperl
RUN make -C /shared/perl-5.22.1
RUN make -C /shared/perl-5.22.1 test
RUN make -C /shared/perl-5.22.1 install
```

Error:

```
Step 14/20 : ADD http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.22.1.tar.gz /shared
Downloading 15.92 MB/15.92 MB
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 24f3b38dee5f
Step 15/20 : RUN tar -xzf perl-5.22.1.tar.gz
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 42ecf82ce73d
Step 16/20 : RUN /shared/perl-5.22.1/Configure -des -Dprefix=/opt/perl-5.22.1/localperl
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dfe8d71f5ff1
Step 17/20 : RUN make -C /shared/perl-5.22.1/
 ---> Running in 2766b0c8e9a5
make: Entering directory `/shared/perl-5.22.1'
make: Leaving directory `/shared/perl-5.22.1'
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
The command '/bin/sh -c make -C /shared/perl-5.22.1/' returned a non-zero code: 2
ish-mac:testanalyse ish$ ls -l
```

Can anyone help me fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the README says, simply run `make`, but change directory to the root of the source code (/shared/perl-5.22.1):

```
FROM amazonlinux
WORKDIR /shared
RUN yum -y install gcc
ADD http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.22.1.tar.gz /shared
RUN tar -xzf perl-5.22.1.tar.gz

WORKDIR /shared/perl-5.22.1
RUN ./Configure -des -Dprefix=/opt/perl-5.22.1/localperl

RUN make
RUN make test
RUN make install
```

README:

```
INSTALLATION
============

If you're using a relatively modern operating system and want to
install this version of Perl locally, run the following commands:

  ./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl
  make test
  make install
```